# How to run js code with DOM before page load?

Tags: javascript

I am making a javascript function that adds script and css elements into my head section, but I need to run that before the page is loaded, how could I do that?

Comment: Are you aware that adding scripts or stylesheets after the page has loaded will load, parse, and apply them?

Comment: no, I wasn't, I thought that it didnt do that

Answer (score 0):

you can run script after DOM tree is loaded not images and sounds etc just DOM

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
 console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
 });
```

Comment: okay, but the issue with that is that I need to dynamically load scripts, and those scripts dynamically load other things. So for example, my script adds a script element, which needs to get loaded and run it's window.onload (or jquery version of that, cant remember it right now)

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out my issue.
The issue was that it was loading the scripts, but it wasn't running their window.onload. When I made the function run staticly instead of a window.onload, it works fine. Thanks for the help!

EDIT: This also works to dynamically load the CSS stylesheets, so YAY

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to send just the script in your `html` and then have it bootstrap the rest of the page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
  // do whatever you're trying to do with your code
  $.get('path/to/page/partial.html').done(handleNewPartial);
</script>
</head>
<html>
```

The reason you can't do it the way you're asking is that your code is always included as a DOM element on the page, ie it has to be delivered inside a `<script>` tag to be used by the browser. So by definition your script can not be used until after your html has been parsed into the DOM.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah, I finally figured out that out. I thought that it loaded the scripts from top to bottom with everything else, instead it actually loads them after everything else, but runs the window.onload at a different time.

Comment: Glad you figured it out - please mark an answer as accepted so others know :) (even if it's your own answer)